# Execute stored procedure in SQL Server using CodeIgniter SQLSRV

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that contains 4 insert processes:

- Process 1, Lookup data from Chief 1 and insert it to Archive table
- Process 2, Lookup data from Chief 2 and insert it to Archive table
- Process 3, Lookup data from Chief 3 and insert it to Archive table
- Process 4, Lookup data from Chief 4 and insert it to Archive table

All processes work in the stored procedure, so the application only calls to run the one stored procedure.

When I execute using CodeIgniter (SQLSRV) with command:

```
EXEC getwage_bcmbs @date_start = '2020-04-28'
```

The process only works up to process #2. Then the result only 2 records in `Archive` table.

But, when I execute the command in SQL Server Management Studio, the processes normally run until process 4. Then the result are 4 records.

Please can anybody help me? What is the problem? Is it caused by some trouble in the stored procedure or inside SQLSRV?

- PHP Version 7.2.18-1 + Ubuntu18.04.1 + deb.sury.org+1
- SQL Server 2016

Comment: We need specific details of the SP to see how that might happen.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Dale ,  The problem already solved by Add " SET NOCOUNT ON ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved
I currently need to add

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

to my Store Procedure.

In my SP, I make the process that insert to Temporary table and when continue to process 2, the temporary table will be deleted.
When the temporary table return 0 data to delete, then the SQL Server return message that handled by SQLSRV as a complete process messages. Then the process stop in the process 2.

May be that why my SP not run completely when i call it from SQLSRV. But normally run when i call it using SMSS or SQL Server Client programs

Thanks StackOverflow